# How to get the Greek Characters from particular font through autoinst or LCDF typetool?

Tags: greek

My text font is ArnoPro font, i need this font also for greek, I converted the otf font through autoinst/LCDF type tool. I am using MiKTeX 2.9, (I know we can get the greek charactes in XeLaTeX, but i want to work with latex2e with MiKTeX)

How to get the greek Characters through autoinst like minionpro.sty ?

Comment: You would need to write a fontools_lgr.enc along the lines of fontools_t1.enc and then try out if autoinst --encoding=lgr works.

Comment: @Ulrike  I am not aware to write the .enc file, is any manual is available to learn/understand the coding in .enc? or how to write the enc file?

Comment: Find fontools_t1.enc open it in your editor and look what it does. It is not difficult to understand, it is only an array of 256 glyph names. The difficult and time consuming part is to find the glyph names ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have created the .enc file it is working now. Thank you

Comment: @vctu Can you advise how to create `.enc` file for the Greek characters in `ArnoPro` font? Please...